# Amazon S3, how to deal with the delay from Upload to Object availability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, paperclip

The app I'm building allows a user to upload a file. The file is uploaded to Amazon S3 in a private bucket.

Then users can download the file, which we allow by creating a time expiring URL:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(attachment.path(style || attachment.default_style), attachment.bucket_name, :expires_in => expires_in, :use_ssl => true)
```

The problem we're having is that there is a short delay from upload to availability via the AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for. If users try to download the file right after the upload, Amazon errors with:

```
215412-NameError (uninitialized constant Attachment::AWS):
215413-  app/models/attachment.rb:32:in `authenticated_url'
215414-  app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:33:in `show'
```

Any ideas on how to optimize, deal with this delay?

Thanks

Comment: If you know there is the delay, why try to use it immediately? I also haven't noticed any delay. Unless you are talking about 100ms delay after the request. And you are trying to do something with the object immediately after uploading.

Comment: We don't experience this delay either.  Our image uploads are available immediately following upload since we have to process the original image.

Comment: That stack trace looks more like a ruby problem than an amazon issue

Comment: The stack trace does look like Ruby. It looks like you make the URL on demand as a user clicks, which should work but is not needed. Note that you can create time limited URLs for objects which do not exist on S3, so the mere act of creating a URL should never fail. In other words creating an expiring URL requires no bits to be sent back and forth between amazon and your server. These URLs also seem pretty fast to make, so I tend to make them as I build the page, rather than have a special handler.

Comment: @TomAndersen Thanks for that, so what do you imagine theissue is? Any way to debug this?

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been years, but for those who came here with the same issue, here is what I've found.

First of all, it's just how [AWS S3 works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel):

> A process writes a new object to Amazon S3 and immediately lists keys within its bucket. Until the change is fully propagated, the object might not appear in the list.

The best way I have found to deal with this behaviour would be to wait while an uploaded object appears in the list before allow users to download it.

Something like:

```
_put_object(filename)
while True:
    if _file_exists(filename):
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

To check availability we can use [client.head_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) or [client.list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2).

There is an [opinion](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/fastest-way-to-find-out-if-a-file-exists-in-s3) that list_objects_v2 works faster

Comment: For the record, the linked docs (specifically the quoted part) are now updated and state: "A process writes a new object to Amazon S3 and immediately lists keys within its bucket. The new object appears in the list."
I came upon this when investigating possible delays in between put acknowledgement and file availability. But I'm far from certain it's still how it works today and the architecture hasn't changed.

Answer (score 2):

How long of a delay are you seeing? How often is this happening?

We upload directly to s3 from the browser using https://github.com/PRX/s3-swf-upload-plugin , and by the time I get a callback that the file exists, I have never seen an error with it being not yet available.

Another thing we do is to mark the object to one state on first upload, then use an asycnh process to validate the file, and only after it is marked valid do we go ahead and process it.
This causes a delay however, so it may not be such a great answer for you.

Comment: Just because you see no delay in your environment so far, does not mean that you won't get one. I have seen delays of minutes, (but I have uploaded millions of files). If you look at the AWS forums you can find people sometimes encounter delay.